# value error: could not find a format to write the specified file in s% mode

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to run the following interpolation python code.

[MNIST latent interpolation](https://github.com/BKHMSI/MNIST-Latent-Interpolation/blob/master/main.py)

I used `python main.py  --start-num 1 --end-num 3 --out-name 1-3` command to run the code and faced the error:

> value error: could not find a format to write the specified file in s mode (Please check the screenshot).

[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mVmIT.png)

Any hint will be appreciated.

Comment: You can attach command that you use to run the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem could be generated by `--out-name 1-3`.

`imageio.mimsave(os.path.join(out_path, out_name), resized_imgs)` is fuction that create your file. This requires extension of file example 'file.gif'.

Try to run your code in like this :
`python main.py  --start-num 1 --end-num 3 --out-name name.gif`

In addition, I enclose all the commands allowed:

```
parser.add_argument('-t', '--train',action="store_true", default=False)
 
parser.add_argument('-e', '--epochs',type=int, default=250, help='number of epochs for training')

parser.add_argument('-b', '--batch-size',type=int, default=400, help='batchsize used in training')

parser.add_argument('-s', '--save-interval', type=int, default=50, help='save model every interval')

parser.add_argument('-g', '--generate',  action="store_true", default=True)

parser.add_argument('-i', '--imsize',    type=int, default=128,  help='image size of generated gif')

parser.add_argument('-a', '--start-num', type=int, default=9,help='count down/up starts with this number')

parser.add_argument('-z', '--end-num',   type=int, default=0,    help='count down/up ends with this number')

parser.add_argument('-n', '--n-steps',   type=int, default=30,   help='number of steps used in latent interpolation')

parser.add_argument('-o', '--out-path',  type=str, default="output", help='path to generated gif')

parser.add_argument('-l', '--out-name',  type=str, default="countdown.gif", help='name of generated gif')

parser.add_argument('-m', '--model-path',type=str, default="models/model-250.h5", help='path to saved model')
```